# redux state is not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Action:

```
export const fetchNewsSuccess = (article) => ({
  type: NewsActionTypes.FETCH_NEWS_SUCCESS,
  payload: article,
});
export const fetchNewsBeginAsync = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const collectionRef = fireStore.collection('news');
    dispatch(fetchNewsBegin());

    collectionRef
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        dispatch(fetchNewsSuccess(snapshot));
      })
      .catch((error) => dispatch(fetchNewsFailure(error.message)));
  };
};
```

Reducer

```js
const newsReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.payload) {
    case NewsActionTypes.FETCH_NEWS_BEGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
      };
    case NewsActionTypes.FETCH_NEWS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        news: action.payload,
      };
  }
}
```

[redux-logger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nYyq.png)

I'm trying to get article data from firebase database, fetching data in action (with redux-thunk) fetchNewsBeginAsync then my action has payload but state not updating can anyone help me pls

Comment: try to log `snapshot` and see what you are getting from firebase

Comment: you should log out underneath the case to see what the action type and payload are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `collectionRef.get()` will return a `QuerySnapshot` which contains 0 or more `QueryDocumentSnapshot`. You have to loop through the documents in `QuerySnapshot` object and call the `.data()` method on each document to extract the data.

```
export const fetchNewsBeginAsync = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const collectionRef = fireStore.collection('news');
    dispatch(fetchNewsBegin());

    collectionRef
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
         // extract the data first
         const results = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
         // dispatch your action with results as payload
         dispatch(fetchNewsSuccess(results));
      })
      .catch((error) => dispatch(fetchNewsFailure(error.message)));
  };
};
```

There is also an error in the reducer. You should be checking `action.type` as condition in the `switch` statement.

```
const newsReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NewsActionTypes.FETCH_NEWS_BEGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
      };
    case NewsActionTypes.FETCH_NEWS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        news: action.payload,
      };
  }
}
```

Comment: same result, also isFetching state not updating

Comment: Can you `console.log(querySnapshot.docs)` and share what it logs to the console.

Comment: ```
t
bE: null
docs: Array(1)
0: n {nE: t, $c: t, lE: n, dE: false, fE: false, …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
empty: (...)
hE: undefined
metadata: t {hasPendingWrites: false, fromCache: false}
nE: t {qT: FirebaseAppImpl, UT: t, INTERNAL: {…}, Nc: t, KT: "[DEFAULT]", …}
pE: t {path: n, collectionGroup: null, xt: Array(0), filters: Array(0), limit: null, …}
query: (...)
size: (...)
vE: null
yE: t {query: t, docs: t, ss: t, docChanges: Array(1), ns: t, …}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: i mean not just news state, isFetching state should be true after FETCH_NEWS_BEGIN action

Comment: There was a nasty bug in the reducer, you were checking the condition `switch(action.payload)` that why the reducer was always returning the default state. I updated the answer. I think that should solve the problem.